# storing image state with redux in component A and fetching in Component B in react native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, redux, react-redux

I am working with expo camera and I am trying to store the image taken and pass it on to another screen as profile picture. however I cannot seem to figure it out. I am roughly new to redux, and I am not very certain if I am doing it right. kindly review my code below

ImageReducer.js

```
  import { ADD_IMAGE } from '../actions/types';

  const initialState = {
    latestImage: null,
  };

  const ImageReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
      case ADD_IMAGE:
        return {
          ...state,
          url: action.url
        };

      default:
        return state;

    }
  };

  export default ImageReducer;
```

ProfileImageAction.js

```
  import { ADD_IMAGE} from './types';

  export const ProfileImageAction = (url) => {
    return {
      type: ADD_IMAGE,
      url
    };
  };
```

reducers/index.js

```
    import { combineReducers } from 'redux';
    import ImageReducerfrom './ImageReducer';

    export default combineReducers({
      image: ImageReducer
    });
```

TakePicture.js

```
    import { Camera, Permissions } from 'expo';
    import { connect } from 'react-redux';
    import { ProfileImageAction } from '../../../../.././src/actions';

    class TakePicture extends Component {

      constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
          hasCameraPermission: null,
          type: Camera.Constants.Type.back,
          latestImage: null
        };
      }


      takePicture = async (latestImage) => {
        if (this.camera) {
          console.log('');

          const photo = await this.camera.takePictureAsync({ base64: true });

          this.setState({
            foo: Math.random()
          });

          const formData = new FormData();
          formData.append('image', photo.base64);
          formData.append('type', 'base64');

          this.setState({
            latestImage: photo.uri,
            isCameraVisible: false
          });
      }

      this.props.dispatch(ProfileImageAction (latestImage));
      };

    render() {
      return (
        .....
      );
    } }

    const mapStateToProps = ({ state }) => {
      return {
        image: state
      };
    };


    export default connect(mapStateToProps, { ProfileImageAction })(TakePicture);
```

ImageContainer.js

```
     import { connect } from 'react-redux';

    class ImageContainer extends Component {

      render() {
        console.log(this.props);
        return (

                      <View style={styles.imageContainer}>
                        <Image
                          style={styles.imageStyle}
                          source={this.props.profilePicture}
                        />
                      </View>
                  )

                }

              }
    function mapStateToProps(state) {
      return {
        profilePicture: state.profilePicture
      };
    }

    export default connect(mapStateToProps, null)(ImageContainer);
```

Comment: "store the image taken and pass it on to another screen as profile picture" It's unclear to me what you're trying to achieve, probably for other readers as well. Could you maybe try to describe your issue in more details?

Comment: I am using the expo.camera to take a photo, I want to pass that taken image to another class component, from takePicture.js to imagecontainer.js

Comment: you have a mistake here source={{ uri: this.props.profilePicture }}

Comment: I am getting this error   
" error: c++ exception in 'nativeFlushQueueImmediate' "